# Snowflake Connection String - Using a Vanity URL

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net to connect to and query our Snowflake instance. We currently have a vanity url setup for Snowflake so that we can go to `https://X.snowflakecomputing.com/` to access the Console.
I have been using `X.snowflakecomputing.com` as the Host part of my connection string (https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net#create-a-connection).

Does anyone know if this is okay or should I always be using the full `{account}.{region}.snowflakecomputing.com` as my Host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From documentation:

> [Where are Account Identifiers Used](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-account-identifier.html#where-are-account-identifiers-used)
>
> Account identifiers are required in Snowflake wherever you need to specify the account you are using, including:
>
> - URLs for accessing any of the Snowflake web interfaces.
> - **SnowSQL, drivers, connectors, and other clients for connecting to Snowflake.**
> - 3rd-party applications and services that comprise the Snowflake ecosystem.
> - Features for securing Snowflake internal operations and communication/interaction with external systems.
>   Global features such as Secure Data Sharing and Database Replication and Failover/Failback.
>
> For example, the URL for an account uses the following format:
>
> ```
> account_identifier.snowflakecomputing.com
> ```